# iOS push notification fail

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification, token

Suddenly I am not receiving push notifications to my application, however no change has been made. The error I am getting is:

`Fail to hand off a notification to APNS for the device token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx after a few retries. Please make sure the APNS SSL certificate for the application is correctly generated and the environment i.e. sandbox vs production, is configured correctly.`

I see everything correctly but neither from Postman nor from the app do I get the notifications, however from here https://icloud.developer.apple.com/dashboard/notifications/ I do get them.

Any ideas? I have already visited many pages but I don't see anyone getting the same error as me.

Update:
I have checked and as far as I can see everything is correct.

- The certificates are valid, they do not expire for another month.
- This is the configuration in SAP Mobile Services
  [image]
- I check that the team ID is the same
- In certificates, identifiers and profiles, I have a key and the key id is the same as in SAP mobile services.
  [image]
- I have also tried it on another device and it still does not arrive.
- I have the entlitements in xcode like this:[image]